# Making NLTK work for UTF8 punctuation?

Tags: python, utf-8, nltk

I just started using NLTK and I noticed that it doesn't work well with non-ascii punctuation. For example, `“` is being tagged as a noun. Also, having non-ascii punctuation messes up the POS tagging for the rest of the words because NLTK is interpreting `“` as a word instead of a punctuation.

Is there a setting that can allow NLTK to recognize non-ascii punctuation? Since having a single non-unicode punctuation messes up the POS tagging for the entire document, I can't just replace every `“` with `"`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of such a setting.

But I have similar issues with pos-tagging non-plain-text (text augmented with some xml-like tags in between). These xml-tags are usually not pos-tagged correctly. So I take them out before I start pos-tagging, keep track of their indices and re-insert them after tagging (and then assign them the proper tag manually).
Arguably, the presence or absence of punctuation won't change nltk's pos-tagging output that much, so you could try the same. Especially since I guess your set of 'problematic' punctuation characters is pretty limited?